# Проверить что bean был создан и не null

Tags: java, spring

Есть ли какой способ проверить что бин был создан? с помощью аннотации а не простым if.

у меня есть сервис который загружает прописанный в xml бин кэша

```
@Autowired
private CacheRun cacheRun;
```

ну и далее в коде я часто где этот cacheRun дергаю. Вот хочется как то понимать создался ли бин или нет.

Comment: у вас спринг конкекст не поднимется если он не смог найти бин для инжекта